# What the parentheses means in chrome devtools memory tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I am checking memory leak of my project, when i make an allocation instrumentation on timeline, I find the most of leak are in parentheses, like (array), (compiled code) and (system).
[image: Memory tab]

What is the difference between (array) and Array?

Answer (score 0):

They represent "group" entries as the Constructor column (and others) show "totals". So that column represents a number of Objects of a certain type that have been constructed in code.  If there are not parentheses, then a DOM Element or Document fragment is represented there.

It should make sense then that all memory leaks are found in those "groups".

For a clearer explanation I recommend you review the docs found here:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots#summary_view